# upper and lower bounds of a symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix given by $A^\top B A$

where $0< \underline \mu I \leq A \leq\bar \mu I$, $A = A^\top$ and $ 0 < B$.

Can I say it holds that $ 0 < \underline \mu^2 B\leq A^\top B A \leq \bar \mu^2 B$ ?

Comment: what do you mean by $A>B$ ?

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, let $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&2}$ and $B=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&1}$. Then
$$
ABA-B=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&3}
\quad \text{ and }\quad 4B-ABA=\pmatrix{6&2\\ 2&0}.
$$
Clearly, $0<I\le A\le2I$, but both $B\le ABA$ and $ABA\le4B$ are false because $\det(ABA-B)=-1<0$ and $\det(4B-ABA)=-4<0$.